# DropDownList не присваивает значение при сохранение модели

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Есть модель - CheckModel. В поля Category и CategoryId (пробовал сохранять в класс и в обычное числовое значение) не сохраняется значение из DropDoприwnList. Что я делаю не так? Вроде все делаю по туториалам и вопросам, которые присутствуют здесь. Будет здорово, если Вы подскажите как можно значение положить в класс, заранее спасибо.

CategoryModel:

```
public class CategoryModel : BaseTypeModel {
}

public abstract class BaseTypeModel {
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Модель:

```
    public class CheckModel {
        [Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string Discription { get; set; }

        public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

        public bool IsPriority { get; set; }

        public bool IsCompleted { get; set; }
        
        //[Required]
        //public CategoryModel Category { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }


        [Required]
        public string UserId { get; set; }
    }
```

Вью

```
@model Simply.CheckListMaster.PL.AspNet.Models.CheckLists.CheckModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Check</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Title" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Discription" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Discription" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Discription" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StartDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="StartDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="StartDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="EndDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="EndDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="EndDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="IsPriority" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsPriority)
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CategoryId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="CategoryId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Categories as SelectList"></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="CategoryId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Контроллер

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create() {
    await GetCategoriesToView();

    return View();
}

private async Task GetCategoriesToView() {
     var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
     var dtoCategories = await _mediator.Send(new GetCategoriesByUserId(userId));

     var viewCategories = dtoCategories.Select(c => new CategoryModel {
         Id = c.Id,
         Name = c.Name
     });

     ViewData["Categories"] = new SelectList(viewCategories, "Id", "Name");
}
```

Comment: В поле Category модели никак не сохранить. А вот почему не сохраняет в CategoryId - загадка: сделано по туториалам всё правильно, у меня аналогичный код в проектах. Попробуйте для начала поделить вопрос пополам, чтобы понять где у вас ошибка: посмотрите в браузере, что передаётся в POST на сервер, есть ли там CategoryId или нет. Если передаётся - то проблема на сервере с биндингом, если не передаётся - стоит внимательно посмотреть, какой html-код отрендерился для select option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Рекомендации**

1. Для приема модели с клиента на сервер используйте отдельный метод с атрибутом `[HttpPost]`.
2. Для HTML-элементов интерфейса используйте HTML-хелперы, т.e. `@Html.*`.
3. Не применяйте наследование к моделям (даже если много моделей имеют 90% одинаковых членов). По опыту скажу, что это усложняет понимание вашего кода другим разработчиком, модель предметной области и это приводит к сложностям валидации.

**Решение**

Я создал метод

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CheckModel model)
{
    await GetCategoriesToView();
    return View(model);
}
```

В модели `CheckModel` раскомментировал

```
[Required]
public CategoryModel Category { get; set; }
```

В представлении закомментировал `div` с `"CategoryId"`

```
<!--
<div class="form-group">
<label asp-for="CategoryId" class="control-label"></label>
<select asp-for="CategoryId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Categories as SelectList"></select>
<span asp-validation-for="CategoryId" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
-->
```

Вместо этого добавил Razor-ские HTML-хелперы

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Category.Name)
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Category.Id, ViewBag.Categories as SelectList)
```

Также изменил тег `form`, указав метод Post

```
<form asp-action="Create" method="post">
```

Модель приходит вместе объектом `CategoryModel`

[image: Представление]

[image: Метод, принимающий модель]

Comment: `Для HTML-элементов интерфейса используйте HTML-хелперы, т.e. @Html.*.` - совет неправильный. Для `Asp.Net Core` HTML-хелперы признаны устаревшими, надо использовать `Tag Helpers`.

Comment: В примере использовал: var viewCategories = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(c => new CategoryModel {
         Id = c,
         Name = c.ToString()
     });

Comment: @Neomaster спасибо, разобрался, был мой косяк. Все заработало, большое спасибо